# Erro ao utilizar a biblioteca GLM GTX do OpenGL

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, unity3d, opengl

Estou tentando compilar no linux ubuntu um projeto que utiliza os quaternions para rotação de objetos em 3D da biblioteca glui, quando vou compilar o código o sistema acusa o seguinte erro :

O Codigo diz que o erro tem alguma coisa a ver com a biblioteca GLM/GTX no 
transform.hpp e quaternion.hpp

Não faço ideia como resolver preciso de ajuda ! Muito obrigado.

[image: ERRO AO COMPILAR CÓDIGO COM QUATERNION]

Segue o trecho do erro :

In file included from camera.h:18:0,
                 from camera.cpp:2:
/usr/include/glm/gtx/transform.hpp:23:3: error: #error "GLM: GLM_GTX_transform is an experimental extension and may change in the future. Use #define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL before including it, if you really want to use it."
 # error "GLM: GLM_GTX_transform is an experimental extension and may change in the future. Use #define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL before including it, if you really want to use it."
   ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp:20:0,
                 from camera.h:20,
                 from camera.cpp:2:
/usr/include/glm/gtx/norm.hpp:21:3: error: #error "GLM: GLM_GTX_norm is an experimental extension and may change in the future. Use #define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL before including it, if you really want to use it."
 # error "GLM: GLM_GTX_norm is an experimental extension and may change in the future. Use #define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL before including it, if you really want to use it."
   ^~~~~
In file included from camera.h:20:0,
                 from camera.cpp:2:

Comment: Tem como colocar o erro em texto aqui também ? Não só fica mais fácil de ler que nesse fundo transparente, como passa também a ser pesquisavel.

Comment: Sim tem como sim , Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro indica que você está tentando utilizar extensões [GTX experimentais](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/api/a00165.html) e, para isso, é necessário definir uma macro para habilitar o uso dessas extensões antes de incluí-las no código.

Para solucionar o problema, defina a macro abaixo no arquivo `camera.h`, **antes** de incluir os arquivos de cabeçalho das extensões:

```
#define GLM_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL
```

Caso existam outros locais onde você utilize essas extensões, defina a mesma macro antes de carregá-las.

Observe que, conforme a documentação, essas extensões não são recomendadas e estão sujeitas a mudanças futuramente.

Comment: Nossa Você é fera hem ! Muito obrigado. O que uma simples linha de código não faz hem ? . Valeu!